# Schema.org markup in emails

Tags: html-email, schema.org, email-client

Is there some table that lists compatibility in email clients with Schema.org markup? I know Gmail works, but what about other clients?

Edit: For clarification, i'm asking what email clients support schema.org markup in HTML emails

Comment: What do you mean with compatibility?

Comment: Yes, sorry compatibility

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand. I was asking what you mean with compatibility -- in your eyes, when is an email client compatible?

Comment: Gmail, Outlook.com, Yahoo Mail, Roundcube. Various browser based email clients. I can't imagine proper email clients like Outlook/Thunderbird/Mail will support this feature anytime soon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Available Encodings

> **Note**: Although [schema.org](https://schema.org/) vocabulary recommends many different encodings, including [RDFa](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-primer/), [Microdata](http://dev.w3.org/html5/md-LC/) and [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/), only `gmail` supports it. Markup for `Apple mail` and `MS Outlook` differs.

## Most Popular Email Clients

The word most popular email clients are: 
[image: The Word Most Popular Email Clients]

#### Markup for Apple Mail

Unfortunately, I don't know any mentions of Schema.org usage for Apple Mail.

But, you can create and customize your e-mail stationary. [There](https://www.thegraphicmac.com/how-to-create-customized-os-x-mail-stationery-in-snow-leopard/) are [many](https://kddidit.com/2010/11/05/create-custom-email-templates-in-mail/) howtos to [quickstart](https://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-Customizing-of-Apple-Mail-Stationary/).

Also, you can use [Fira-Stationery](https://github.com/cedwardsmedia/Fira-Stationery) by by Corey Edwards as a starter template. It's a simple, clean, unobtrusive, content-first template.

[image: Fira-Stationery]

#### Markup for Gmail

As for email markup, there are two available for Gmail: [JSON-LD (recommended)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/formats/json-ld) and [Microdata](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/formats/microdata)

#### Markup for MS Outlook

Instead of `microdata` markup, there are [Actionable message cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card)
See [Get started with actionable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email#sending-actionable-messages-via-email) for details

## Howto check your markup before sending

Anyway, you can test your markup using different email-testing tools, such as:

- [Litmus Email Testing](https://litmus.com/email-testing)
- [HTML Email Check and Validation Tool | HTML Email Check](https://www.htmlemailcheck.com/)

## Useful guides

- [Structured Data in Email Marketing – Litmus Software, Inc.](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-structured-data-in-email-marketing) by Litmus
- [How to add Schema.org markup to your email marketing](https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/08/03/how-to-add-schema-org-markup-to-your-email-marketing/)
- [Differences between JSON-LD, Microdata, and RDFa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/342024) answered to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328567/how-does-microdata-rdfa-compare-to-json-ld)